# Visual Studio - Database

Tags: database, vb.net, visual-studio-2013

I'm experimenting with coding a database-driven application in Visual Studio 2013. Newbie here, please bear with me...

I'm looking at either using a local .mdf file (preferred due to simplicity) or a database management system (suggestions? I'm only familiar with MySQL).

Questions :-

1. My computing knowledge is rusty, but has MySQL fallen out of favor with the programming world? If so, what are some free alternatives?
2. It seems excessively complicated to handle data in Visual Studio..? All the tutorials I'm looking at require me to a. create a dataset from existing db tables b. manipulate the data in the dataset c. write the updated data back into the db? Am I getting that right?

And it generates a bunch of additional classes, TableAdaptor, DataTable, etc etc...

Is it advisable to use pure SQL in Visual Basic to query and write from the database itself? Or do I have to bite the bullet and properly learn all the above?

Thanks for any help/advice provided!

Comment: As someone new to programming, I've been looking into it myself recently. I spent about a week trying to get a test database to work with visual studio and LINQ, but I couldn't work it out. Seemed very overly complicated. 

Decided to try PHP with databases instead (since I really just wanted to learn how databases interact with programming languages), and that only took a few hours to work out how to setup and start writing code -- and that was with learning PHP at the same time.

Comment: Yes you can use _pure SQL to query and write to from database_.  [Example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hdt3k85x(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: You can search and learn SqlHelper, Strong Typed DataSet, Linq to Entities step by step, in the order ADO.NET develops.

Answer (score 0):

You can look into Entity Framework.

Entity Framework (EF) is an object-relational mapper that enables .NET developers to work with relational data using domain-specific objects. It eliminates the need for most of the data-access code that developers usually need to write.

Visit [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/ef.aspx) for more information.

You can also look at [SQL Server express](http://www.microsoft.com/web/platform/database.aspx) for your DBMS

Answer (score 0):

Question 2: Yes, pretty much, unless you are starting with an existing DB and then you can skip the create DB and tables step. For really small apps you may recreate the db and tables on demand, or at least at install time.

The db and create steps are often backend specific so you may be tackling a learning curve that has marginal value in the future.

The lowest level recent tool for db access in Visual Studio is ADO.Net. There are two flavors: SQL Server and OLEDB. The main coding difference is in getting a connection established, after that the dataadpters, datasets, datatables, and dataviews are about the same with the differences being at the SQL level dealing with db capabilities.

If you are going to work in VS on Windows I'd suggest you use one of the MS variants for SQL Server: SQL Server 20xx, SQL Express 20xx, or SQL CE (Compact edition). The latter two are free and distributable. Code developed should run across all three. SQL CE runs in process with your app and SQL Express runs as a service. Both need to be installed on the PC but CE is easier.

If you are headed towards supporting web pages then the MySQL (MariaDB which may avoid licensing issues MySQL is tangled up in - the reason for you question 1), or something similar may be the way to go. I haven't worked with these but I think they connect via OLEDB.

Unless you expect to write apps that are distributed and need to set up their own databases I'd suggest you separate the two learning curves. I'd start with the coding against the various sample databases MS provides. Look for a sample targeted to the DB engine you choose.

For coding I'd suggest you start with a simple form with a datagridview to display your work. Build a code library for low level read only tasks like GetDataTable(), GetDataView(), GetScalar(), ExecuteSQL(), etc. and create reusable code.

Next step would be to learn how to use updatable datasets. This code is a bit harder to make reusable but the patterns are common for similar tasks.

Next would be binding. Binding can be done at code level or via controls added by VS to your "bound" forms. For simple apps the VS tools are fine but they don't scale well. Hence the suggestion in another post for Entity Framework. You can do the binding and navigation with your own code using local instances of the VS controls.

LINQ is cute but a distraction IMO. It allows you to query all kinds of objects, which is nice, but not really needed for most apps.